# how to share a bool value between UIControl classes

Tags: swift

I have two classes , I need to pass the bool value from class one to  class two. if it is true then need to print something in the second class.

How can I pass Bool Value between two classes in swift

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking

Comment: Are you trying to mix SwiftUI into a UIKit project?

Comment: I am actually trying to pass a bool value between two classes , both classes are UIControl , I mean Class FirstClass : UIControl {}  and Class SecondClass : UIControl {}

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a value to your property before the superclass initializer is called. So it should be probably:

```
public required init?(coder : NSCoder){
 self.radioSelected = false
super.init(coder : coder)
_init()
}
```

and

```
public override init (frame : CGRect){
self.radioSelected = false
super.init(frame : frame)
_init()
}
```

and the errors should vanish

or even shorter:

```
@Binding  var radioSelected : Bool = false
```